# history.back() does not appear to wait for click despite React's onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, onclick, flow-router

I am trying to make a link for a go back button with `<a href='#' onClick={history.back()} >`
for a specific view that I am rendering with React and Meteor.
my goal is to be able to allow the user to go back to the previous page without having to pass parameters and without forcing the user to use the browser back button.

Problem: when running this code, the view with back button does not even render and the `history.back()` seems to be automatically triggered instead of waiting for the onClick event to be triggered (user clicks button)

```
import React from 'react';

const UnitButtonComponent = () => {
    return (
    <div>
        <a href='#' onClick={history.back()} >
            <button type='button' name='go back' />
        </a>
    </div>
    )
};

export default UnitButtonComponent;
```

I also use flowrouter as my router.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the () after `history.back`. The stuff inside the {} is evaluated when the render method is called.

If you delete the (), you'll assign the history.back function to the onClick prop, and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the method immediately

Do this instead:

```
<a href='#' onClick={() => history.back()} >
```